# How to find top 10 sum of each match?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I mean if I have several X and several Y
and I do a match like this:

```
X -[ W ]-> Y
```

With X and Y related by several W ( there can be several W between same pairs (X,Y) )

I want top ten X for each Y with the property sum(W.property)

If I return

```
return Y , sum(W.property) , X order by sum(W.property) desc Limit 10
```

I Just get 10 but I need for every Y,

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH X -[ W ]-> Y
WITH Y, sum(W.property) AS total, X
ORDER BY total DESC
WITH Y, collect({sum: total, X: X})[0..10] AS values
UNWIND values AS value
RETURN Y, value.sum, value.X
```

You can actually skip the `UNWIND` and just change that second `WITH` to a `RETURN` if you're OK with it returning it as an array.  It would be a bit more efficient because you're not repeating values of `Y` over and over.  If you were going to do that you could even change the map structure into an array like this:

```
collect([total, X])[0..10]
```

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to fix some typos and to prepend the `MATCH` clause to make it clearer. But otherwise a very nice solution.